# Add labels to a d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, firebase, dc.js

I have a d3 barchart for which I pull data from firebase. I want to add the labels to the x-axis. Here is the code of my barchart:

```
new Firebase('https://exampl.firebaseIO.com/example').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var lst = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {lst.push(childSnapshot.val());});
    var magValue = new crossfilter(lst).dimension(function (d) {return d.count;});
    var magLabel = new crossfilter(lst).dimension(function (d) {return d.Owner;});

    dc.barChart("#dc-magnitude-chart")
        .width(480)
        .height(150)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
        .dimension(magValue)    // the values across the x axis
        .group(magValue.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.count;}))                            // the values on the y axis
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .centerBar(true)    
        .gap(56)       // bar width Keep increasing to get right then back off.
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 7.5]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {return v;}); 
    dc.renderAll();

    });
```

magValue is the simple count of occurences and it is diplayd on the x-axis. I want the names that are stored in magLabel variable to be displayed below the counts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference: in the comments on @bencripps answer, the OP talks about using `xAxis.tickValues(['One','two','three','four','five','six','seven'])`.

`tickValues` is actually if you want to specify custom ticks within the scale you're using. Right now, you're using a linear scale:

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 7.5]))
```

so it expects your tick values to be points on that scale where it can draw ticks. If you had something more like `xAxis.tickValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])`, it should work.

However, it sounds like you don't actually want a linear scale. d3 also has other scale types, and it sounds like the one you want is an [Ordinal Scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). Ordinal scales are the scales you typically think of for bar charts; they're a type of scale that has a discrete domain. In this case, you could try changing your scale to something like:

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['One','two','three','four','five','six','seven']))
```

so it uses an ordinal scale instead. Since you're using dc.js, you'll also need to specify

```
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

so that it knows to use ordinal marks.

Comment: dc 2.0 will deduce the domain values, so you don't have to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple code for adding an X axis; you will have to fiddle with the domain, and range to get the desired length, and number of ticks.

```
var XaxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,150]) //you will have to set the domain, not sure what you want
    .range([0, magValue.length)

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(XaxisScale)
    .ticks( magValue.length ) // this you will need to set as well

var xAxisGroup = $('"#dc-magnitude-chart').append("g")
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(5,8)')
    .call(xAxis);
```

**note**, the `.call(xAxis)` is what is actually appending the X axis to your chart.

Comment: my code creates an axis alright with numbers as tick values. I am trying to use text as tick values. The text is stored in the magLabel variable. I have been looking through the dc.js documentation and there is a command `xAxis.tickValues([]). I was trying to use it, but could not make to work. Your answer does not address my question, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: Can you include what you tried with `tickValues` and what went wrong in the OP?

Comment: @MikePrecup first, I comment out the `xAxis.tickFormat()` and then add this `xAxis.tickValues(['One','two','three','four','five','six','seven'])`
Does not display the ticks at all. If I dont comment out the  `xAxis.tickFormat()` the chart does render. I have seven bars in the chart.